# how do i solve issues regarding external style sheet link which is not in the same directory of the programming file,but works?

Tags: css

I programmed a page (read index.php) including front end and back end operations,and in between i included a link `-<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`, but there is no effect on the front end application whether I put this css file in the same directory of index.php or delete it. But when I remove the link from the programming page then the front end page is affected. So, how do I conclude this situation? Please anybody help me. I don't understand how the css file works when it is not in the directory where programming page lies.

Comment: there is the link <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information given it sounds like the file is being included from a cache.

Deleting the file on the server wouldn't affect the page render since there is a locally cached version of the file but deleting the link would prevent the browser from loading the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when working on your localhost you have to put the entire path of the CSS file, not just it's normal location as you do when on a live website. Copy your entire path in the href on the link tag and see if it works.

Normally, if the file is in the same place as your index, you put the href the same way it is written in your example above. If your CSS file is in another folder, you would put ../style.css instead. Writing like that, will move up one folder.